# What is the algorithm Who have the worst complexity O(2^2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Their are many complexity type like O(1) ...
But the worst complexity is O(2^2^n)
Is There an algorithm Who have this complexity O(2^2^n)?
Who is it?

Comment: Why would you think the worst complexity is O(2^2^n)?

Comment: O(A(27, n)) is a little worse, where A is the Ackerman's function.

Comment: Does an upper limit to complexity exist…? Hence, can there be such as thing as *absolute worst*…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm with complexity `O(2^(2^n))` is: count from `0` to `2^(2^n)-1`, using `2^n` bits.

`O(2^n)` for initialization, and amortized `O(1)` per incrementation.

If you want to output all these numbers, this will require `O(2^(2^n).2^n)` operations, which is - technically - above `O(2^(2^n))`. You can fix by only outputting the first `2^(2^n-1)` numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "the worst" complexity  - for example, if you believe that some function F(n) represents the largest complexity, square it or make `G(n) = 2^F(n)` and so on.

Concerning example  of `O(2^2^n)` algorithm - there are `2^n` n-bits integers. And there are `2^2^n` sets of such integers - you'll get mentioned complexity if some algorithm ought to examine all possible sets (if the time to examine every set is constant, as Yves Daoust noted) to retrieve a result.

Comment: Your last sentence only holds if the time to examine a set is constant.